# Why does the towlower() function not convert the Я to a lower-case я?

Tags: c++, unicode, locale, lowercase, wchar-t

The function `towlower()` doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio 2012. Here's an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <wctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
    wcout << (wchar_t)towlower(L'Я') << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The character remains upper case. Similar questions have been asked here before but I can't find any solutions.

Is there another method I can use to change to lower case?

Comment: [We close all typo questions,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions) by the way.

Comment: @H2CO3: Now you tricked me too :(. See [`towlower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towlower)

Comment: What do you mean? There's no typo.

Comment: No typo it is a valid call. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwctype/towlower/

Comment: You need to manually set a locale since C++ by default uses the invariant C locale, no matter what. I don’t know which Unicode locales are installed on Windows, though.

Comment: @Zeta Damn. Damn! DAMN! This is what happens when I don't RTFM... Sorry. :-(

Comment: Maybe the new title will keep the clowns from trying to close this question. It's actually a very good one, a +1 from me.

Comment: @CodyGray The [tag:visual-studio-2012] tag was quite relevant actually …

Comment: @Konrad Really, why? What changed in VS 2012 that affects this behavior?

Comment: @H2CO3 and now the question has accumulated close votes which tend to attract more close votes. Good call. ;)

Comment: @jalf: Don't you think "too localized" is just a meta-pun?

Comment: @jalf I've flagged this to reflect my mistake, not sure whether moderators can undo wrong close votes, though...

Comment: @CodyGray The *platform* is important. Locales for instance have different names on different platforms and that’s a relevant detail here.

Comment: use ICU. Or better, use ICU thru boost::locale

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the locale-aware version of `tolower`, but don't forget to also set the C locale.

For example:

```
#include <clocale>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    std::wcout << L"The letter is: " << L'Я' << L" => "
               << std::tolower(L'Я', std::locale("")) << std::endl;
}
```

This prints:

```
The letter is: Я => я
```

Using locales in iostreams is tricky business, and there's a whole Pandora's box hidden behind this. For example, you can *imbue* streams with a locale, and you can manage multiple locales at once, and in particular you can have one per thread (which may be necessary for stateful string encoding conversions)... someone should write a book about that (or instead use Boost.Locale).

Answer (score 5):

I see two possibilities. The first one is locale not being set correctly. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h19t214%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The case conversion of `towlower` is locale-specific. Only the characters relevant to the current
>   locale are changed in case. The functions without the `_l` suffix use the currently set locale.

The second one is the source file encoding. `L'Я'` might mean different things based on what your source file is encoded with. It won't work, for example, if you have it in `UTF-8`. Make sure you have it in `UTF-16`. Or to remove any possible confusion put it like this `'\u042F'`

**Update:** On the second thought this whole `L` business is tricky. If the compiler understands the encoding correctly, via BOM for example, it might be fine with `UTF-8` or any other encoding. Important that it should know what the encoding is. It must be very much implementation specific.

**Another update:** To fix the problem try to set locale via:

```
_wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"ru-RU");
```

or use the version that takes the locale as parameter (`_towlower_l`).

And there's also on top of everything a [pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e22ty2t.aspx) that tells the compiler how to treat non-ASCII string literals in the file.

Comment: By default, I believe VC++ treats source files as Windows-1252 encoded (aka almost-but-not-quite Latin1), which means that fancy characters like `Я` are likely to get mangled. So yeah, definitely use `\u042f`. :)

Comment: VC++ does recognize the Unicode BOM and acts accordingly, even in UTF-8 files.

Answer (score 0):

Does it do less damage than towhigher? j/k.  I'm not familiar with the reversed R, but I know that if the character doesn't have a lower case equivalent, to(w)lower will return the original character. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/towlower